# SQL Server Need to Handle NULL values inside Stuff function

Tags: sql-server-2014

[My Required Output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhYua.jpg)I have to concatenate subavlues of a multivalued record with separator and if the middle subvalue is null I have to concatenate with Just separator. I have written the following code.

```
SELECT B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,B.co_code,(select CASE WHEN OTHER_OFFICER IS NOT NULL AND  0 < (SELECT COUNT(C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS C
where C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND C.OTHER_OFFICER IS NULL ) THEN ISNULL(B.OTHER_OFFICER +']',']')
ELSE NULL
END
from EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS A
    where A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
    FOR XML PATH(''))AS ACC_DEB_LIMIT
FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS b
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER,co_code
```

This is working, but even though all the subvalues of a multivalued record are null it is concatenating with the separator and the output is coming like this

[I would like to display NULL incase all the subvalues are null and I need to remove the separator at the ending of the string. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in Advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk2uE.jpg)

I tried this logic also, it is giving me the same result

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,co_code, STUFF(( SELECT  isnull(']'+ OTHER_OFFICER,']') FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS a
WHERE b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '')  alt_account_type
FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS b
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER,co_code;
```

Comment: lease format better the code

Comment: SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,co_code, STUFF(( SELECT isnull(']'+ OTHER_OFFICER,']') FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS a WHERE b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '') alt_account_type FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS b GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER,co_code; This is also giving me the same output

Comment: You are using ISNULL Wrong, When you do isnull(']'+ OTHER_OFFICER,']') and OTHER_OFFICER is NULL you will have ISNULL(']'+NULL,']') and ']'+NULL is not null. Try doing ISNULL(OTHER_OFFICER,'')+']'

Comment: I have to put the separator ']' if the middle subvalue is null for example a,b,c,d are the subvalues then I should display a]b]c]d, if b is missing then I should display a]]c]d. But if d is missing I should display a]b]c. If the last sub value is missing separator should not be displayed. Separator should be placed only if the middle sub values are null.

Comment: Below is my query "SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,co_code, STUFF(( SELECT  isnull(']'+ OTHER_OFFICER,']') FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS a
WHERE b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '')  alt_account_type
FROM EFZ_ACCOUNT_DETAILS b
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER,co_code;"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood your requirements, but will this query solved your problem.

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
 WHEN d IS NULL AND c IS NOT NULL  THEN
   ISNULL(a,'')+']'+ISNULL(b,'')+']'+ c
 WHEN d IS NULL AND c IS NULL AND b IS NOT NULL  THEN 
   ISNULL(a,'')+']'+ b
 WHEN d IS NULL AND c IS NULL AND b IS NULL AND a IS NOT NULL THEN 
   a
 WHEN d IS NULL AND c IS NULL AND b IS NULL AND a IS NULL THEN  
   NULL
 ELSE
   ISNULL(a,'')+']'+ISNULL(']'+b,'')+']'+ISNULL(']'+c,'')+']'+ISNULL(d,'')+']'
```

END
FROM TestTable;

See the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/927b1/15)

Comment: The problem is, here the number of subvalues is not fixed and also in my given example a,b,c and d are not columns they are values of a subvalued column. Please let me know if more clarification is required